# github CODEOWNERS: Disable email notifications for default owners

Tags: github

Is there a way to disable email notifications to the default owners configured in a github CODEOWNERS file?

In [the code owners documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-code-owners), I can only find the following:

> These owners will be the default owners for everything in
>   the repo. Unless a later match takes precedence,
>   @global-owner1 and @global-owner2 will be requested for
>   review when someone opens a pull request.
>
> @global-owner1 @global-owner2

While I do want to have the default code owners, I don't want an email notification being sent out to each code owner for each push, review remark, review approval, merge, etc. It's to much spam and makes it easy to overlook important notifications, e.g., when someone is explicitly added as a reviewer or mentioned in a comment.

Comment: Hi :) I see this question is from 2019. I'm wondering the same thing - did you figure out the answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

The CODEOWNERS notification system can not be turned off. But you can turn off all notification from a repository from the repository settings.

Comment: Dude turn off the ugly highlight and just put normal text

Comment: This seems to be true. But it sucks, because you don't get any real notifications anymore, like when someone mentions you explicitly in a comment.